# The `include` statement in a registered autoloader function runs in the context of which script?

Tags: php

#### Directory structure

```
learner@debian:~$ tree ~/bin
/home/learner/bin
└── php
    ├── Body
    │   ├── Brain.php
    │   └── Cell
    │       └── Neuron.php
    └── main.php

3 directories, 3 files
```

#### First code example

~/bin/php/main.php:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $path = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';
    echo "----- Autoload $class from $path -----\n";
    include $path;
});

use Body\Brain;
$brain = new Brain();
?>
```

~/bin/php/Body/Brain.php:

```
<?php
namespace Body;

use Body\Cell\Neuron;

class Brain
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->brain = new Neuron();
        $this->brain->talk();
    }
}
?>
```

~/bin/php/Body/Cell/Neuron.php:

```
<?php
namespace Body\Cell;
class Neuron
{
    public function talk()
    {
        echo "I am Neuron!\n";
    }
}
?>
```

I am able to execute main.php from my home directory in the following
manner and it works fine:

```
learner@debian:~$ php ~/bin/php/main.php 
----- Autoload Body\Brain from Body/Brain.php -----
----- Autoload Body\Cell\Neuron from Body/Cell/Neuron.php -----
I am Neuron!
```

I am surprised that this works. I expect it to fail when
`$this->brain = new Neuron();` is executed in
`~/bin/php/Body/Brain.php`. When this line is encountered, the
autoloader tries to execute `include 'Body/Cell/Neuron.php'` but there
is no such subdirectory called `Body` inside `~/bin/php/Body`.

#### Second code example

Let me show you why I expect the first code example to fail by showing another code example that is using `include` statements instead of autoloader.

~/bin/php/main.php modified to:

```
<?php
include 'Body/Brain.php';
use Body\Brain;
$brain = new Brain();
?>
```

See that the autoloader is missing now from the above code, and the same
include statement is being used now which was being executed by the
autoloader earlier.

~/bin/php/Body/Brain.php modified to:

```
<?php
namespace Body;

include 'Body/Cell/Neuron.php';

use Body\Cell\Neuron;

class Brain
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->brain = new Neuron();
        $this->brain->talk();
    }
}
?>
```

Note that the same include statement has been added to this code that
was being executed by the autoloader earlier to load `Body\Cell\Neuron`.

Trying to execute this code results in failure.

```
learner@debian:~$ php ~/bin/php/main.php 
PHP Warning:  include(Body/Cell/Neuron.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/learner/bin/php/Body/Brain.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Body/Cell/Neuron.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/learner/bin/php/Body/Brain.php on line 4
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Body\Cell\Neuron' not found in /home/learner/bin/php/Body/Brain.php on line 12
```

This failure is expected because while executing
`include 'Body/Cell/Neuron.php';` in `~/bin/php/Body/Brain.php`, it
doesn't find a subdirectory called `Body` in `~/bin/php/Body`.

#### Question

I know that I can easily fix the second code example by editing
`~/bin/php/Body/Brain.php` to use
`include 'Cell/Neuron.php';` instead of
`include 'Body/Cell/Neuron.php';`. However, my question is not about
why the second code example doesn't work, but about why the first code
example works.

1. When the PHP interpreter is unable to `include 'Body/Cell/Neuron.php'`
    from `~/bin/php/Body/Brain.php` in the second code example, how
    does the autoloader succeed in doing the same include from the same
    PHP file in the first code example?
2. Or am I mistaken? Could it be that in the first code example the
    autoloader is always executing the include statements from
    `~/bin/php/main.php` regardless of where the classes are first
    being used, so `include 'Body/Cell/Neuron.php'` is done at
    `~/bin/php/main.php` and it succeeds because there indeed is a
    subdirectory called `Body` in `~/bin/php`? If this is the case,
    where can I read about it in the official documentation?
3. To summarize our understanding, could you please tell me where the
    registered autoloader function is executed from, in general? From the script
    where the function is defined? From the script where the function
    is registered? Or from the script where a new class is encountered?

Answer (score 1):

Okay it's so:

1. In your first code example you are defining the autoloader. It will include every needed class  with `include`. Imagine it just copy and pastes the code in currently running php script.

   Now in the `Brain.php` file (which has been included, let me say: actually it's running in `main.php` because it has been "copy and pasted" into `main.php`) the class `Neuron` is needed. In `main.php` the autoloader is denfined -> the autoloader is called and loads the `Neuron` class. I think you understand.
2. Your second example doesn't work because when you are going to include `Brain.php` the PHP parser will **before** including `Brain.php` into `main.php`, try to include `Body/Cell/Neuron.php` into `Brain.php`. And you know that this can't work.
3. The autloader is excuted from/in the script you placed it. In your example in `main.php`

(I hope I hasn't confused you more)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's consistent with the results of my experiments. I am trying to understand the underlying rules.

Your second point makes sense. Why can't I argue the same for the first point in this manner: The first example should not work because when `Brain.php` is included by the autoloader, the PHP parser will **before** including `Brain.php` into `main.php`, try to include `Body/Cell/Neuron.php` in `Brain.php` and the autoloader fails to find `Body/Cell/Neuron.php` in the directory containing`Brain.php`.

Where can I find the official word on your point 3?

Comment: @LoneLearner In the first example PHP won't include `Neuron.php` before it includes Brain.php into main.php. Why? Because the PHP parser doesn't knows that `Neuron()` is undefined in `Brain.php`. When it excutes the code out of `Brain.php` it notices: "Whoops? I don't know a class named `Neuron`, but there's my friend autoload...". I can't give you official words for point 3. It seems just logical. But look arround here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Your comment `"Whoops? I don't know a class named Neuron, but there's my friend autoload..."` makes a lot of sense to me now. I have posted the result of my experiments as a separate comment that proves this. I have upvoted your answer. I'll mark your answer as the correct answer if I do not get another answer that can prove the same point by quoting official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering  my own question here. With some experiments it appears to me that the registered autoloader function executes in the context of the script where it is defined, and not where it is registered as an autoloader, and not where new classes are instantiated or used.

However, since this is only an experiment that tries to prove my theory, if anyone can answer my question by quoting official documentation, I'll mark that as the correct answer.

#### Experiment setup

Directory structure:

```
learner@debian:~$ tree ~/bin
/home/learner/bin
└── php
    ├── AutoLoader
    │   ├── AutoLoader.php
    │   └── ClassLoader
    │       └── ClassLoader.php
    ├── Body
    │   ├── Brain.php
    │   └── Cell
    │       └── Neuron.php
    └── main.php

5 directories, 5 files
```

`~/bin/php/AutoLoader/ClassLoader/ClassLoader.php` contains the autoload function called `ClassLoader::loadClass`.

`~/bin/php/AutoLoader/AutoLoader.php` registers the autoload function by calling `spl_autoload_register('Autoloader\\ClassLoader\\ClassLoader::loadClass');`.

#### Source code

`~/bin/php/AutoLoader/AutoLoader.php`:

```
<?php
namespace AutoLoader;

include 'ClassLoader/ClassLoader.php';

class AutoLoader
{
    static public function registerAutoloader()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(
                'Autoloader\\ClassLoader\\ClassLoader::loadClass');
    }
}
?>
```

`~/bin/php/AutoLoader/ClassLoader/ClassLoader.php`:

`~/bin/php/Body/Brain.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Body;

use Body\Cell\Neuron;

class Brain
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->brain = new Neuron();
        $this->brain->talk();
    }
}
?>
```

`~/bin/php/Body/Cell/Neuron.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Body\Cell;
class Neuron
{
    public function talk()
    {
        echo "I am Neuron!\n";
    }
}
?>
```

`~/bin/php/main.php`:

```
<?php
include 'AutoLoader/AutoLoader.php';

use AutoLoader\AutoLoader;
use Body\Brain;

AutoLoader::registerAutoloader();
$brain = new Brain();
?>
```

#### Experiment 1

Executing the above code results in error:

```
learner@debian:~$ php ~/bin/php/main.php 
----- Autoload Body\Brain from Body/Brain.php -----
PHP Warning:  include(Body/Brain.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/learner/bin/php/AutoLoader/ClassLoader/ClassLoader.php on line 9
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Body/Brain.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/learner/bin/php/AutoLoader/ClassLoader/ClassLoader.php on line 9
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Body\Brain' not found in /home/learner/bin/php/main.php on line 8
```

**Observation:** The autoloader could not include `Body/Brain.php` from `~/bin/php/Body/Brain.php`.

#### Experiment 2

Moving `Body` directory to `~/bin/php/AutoLoader` and executing the code still results in error:

```
learner@debian:~$ mv ~/bin/php/Body ~/bin/php/AutoLoader
learner@debian:~$ tree ~/bin
/home/learner/bin
└── php
    ├── AutoLoader
    │   ├── AutoLoader.php
    │   ├── Body
    │   │   ├── Brain.php
    │   │   └── Cell
    │   │       └── Neuron.php
    │   └── ClassLoader
    │       └── ClassLoader.php
    └── main.php

5 directories, 5 files
learner@debian:~$ php ~/bin/php/main.php 
----- Autoload Body\Brain from Body/Brain.php -----
PHP Warning:  include(Body/Brain.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/learner/bin/php/AutoLoader/ClassLoader/ClassLoader.php on line 9
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Body/Brain.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/learner/bin/php/AutoLoader/ClassLoader/ClassLoader.php on line 9
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Body\Brain' not found in /home/learner/bin/php/main.php on line 8
```

**Observation:** The autoloader could not include `Body/Brain.php` from `~/bin/php/AutoLoader/Body/Brain.php`.

#### Experiment 3

Moving `Body` directory to `~/bin/php/AutoLoader/ClassLoader` and executing the code results in success.

```
learner@debian:~$ mv ~/bin/php/AutoLoader/Body ~/bin/php/AutoLoader/ClassLoader/Body
learner@debian:~$ tree ~/bin
/home/learner/bin
└── php
    ├── AutoLoader
    │   ├── AutoLoader.php
    │   └── ClassLoader
    │       ├── Body
    │       │   ├── Brain.php
    │       │   └── Cell
    │       │       └── Neuron.php
    │       └── ClassLoader.php
    └── main.php

5 directories, 5 files
learner@debian:~$ php ~/bin/php/main.php 
----- Autoload Body\Brain from Body/Brain.php -----
----- Autoload Body\Cell\Neuron from Body/Cell/Neuron.php -----
I am Neuron!
```

**Observation:** The autoloader could include `Body/Brain.php` from `~/bin/php/AutoLoader/ClassLoader/Body/Brain.php`.

#### Conclusion

The conclusions of the three experiments seem to indicate that the autoloader is including files with respect to `~/bin/php/AutoLoader/ClassLoader/` directory, i.e. the directory that contains the script that defines the autoloader function.